# servlet request methods implementation

Tags: java, servlets

I'm trying to find implementation of `Servlet` methods but I can't find it.
I was only able to find something like

```
return this._getHttpServletRequest().getHeader(name);
```

And everything else is either `interface` or `class` with reference to `super` or `this.request`.

But I'm curious how methods implemented. Where I can find it?

Comment: Do you want implement your own web container?

Comment: Nope. I am not that cool. I just want to reassure that method `getHeader` is case-insensitive. Because it's described as case-insensitive in `servlet-api` javadoc but whether it should be case-insensitive is not mentioned in servlet speicification

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's up to the servlet container (eg tomcat, jetty, websphere etc) to implement the concrete classes. Each servlet container has it's own implementation. If you fire up a debugger you'll see which implementation you have at runtime.

eg: Jetty's [Request.java](https://github.com/eclipse/jetty.project/blob/master/jetty-server/src/main/java/org/eclipse/jetty/server/Request.java)

Comment: I was trying to search in `trunk` repository of tomcat but still was not able to find implementation. I mean there http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/tomcat/trunk/

Comment: Probably [this class](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/api/org/apache/catalina/connector/Request.html)

Comment: Oh! So is in `request` implementation.

Comment: It depends what you're after, each servlet API interface (request,response,session,servletContext etc) will have a concrete implementation in tomcat's source.